# Exiting Docker Compose V2 run using ^D

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I start Docker container with

```
docker run -ti --rm python:3.9-alpine sh
```

then I am able to exit it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

However, when I use Docker Compose then it does not work

```
services:
  app:
    image: python:3.9-alpine
    tty: true
```

```
docker-compose run app sh
```

Moreover if I start Python shell and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then the process becomes unresponsive and I have to kill the corresponding Docker CLI process.

How do I fix it?

```
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
Docker Compose version v2.0.0-beta.6
macOS 11.3.1
```

---

**Update:**
I have discovered that I was running with experimental Docker Compose V2. Switching to V1 solved the problem. Still, it would be great to solve it even for V2.

Comment: On Windows, I can exit the python shell via `CTRL`+`C`

Comment: Please provide your docker version AND which OS you are running. On MacOS it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Also running on macOS so it's probably related to my shell config (bash)? Updated the question with version info.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden same issue

Comment: Oh I just notice that the Docker Compose version is old. Doh.

Comment: Hmm, on the other hand it comes from the Docker Desktop app...

Comment: Alright, so in the Docker Desktop experimental settings I had Docker Compose V2 enabled. That version has this issue. Switching to V1 fixed the problem. I guess I should not complain about beta version but shouldn't it be better than that?

Comment: Should you not instead upgrade to a newer version of Docker Compose? I use `version: '3.8'` these days ...

Comment: @anatolhiman I believe these are different things. I have to use the one included in the Docker Desktop GUI app anyway. And it's the latest version of it.